# Find and format sub-string in an Excel cell

Tags: excel

As a newbie in Excel programming, I searched the web for a function/UDF/VBA that I could use in Excel to find a sub-string into a cell and bold/colour it in this cell.

I have this kind of sheet below.
- column A contains the text to format partially,
- column B contains the sub-string I am looking for,
- column C contains the position of the sub-string (B) in the string (A)

```
          A          B         C
1  ABCDEFGHIJKLM   FGHI      6-9
2  NOPQRSTUVWXYZ   UVWXY     8-12
...
```

Here what I would need to obtain:

```
          A          B         C
1  ABCDE**FGHI**JKLM   FGHI      6-9
2  NOPQRST**UVWXY**Z   UVWXY     8-12
...
```

Is it possible to apply it for the whole column instead of only line.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' just add a loop and some checkings
Sub t()

Dim heightA As Long
Dim heightB As Long
Dim height As Long
Dim i As Long

heightA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
heightB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
If heightA < heightB Then
    height = heightA
Else
    height = heightB
End If

If height > 1 Then
    For i = 1 To height
        Range("A" & i).Font.Bold = False
        ''Replace the formula with the full string
        Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i).Value
        'Find the starting position of the string in B within the string produced by the formula
        If Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
            myPos = InStr(1, Range("A" & i).Value, Range("B" & i).Value, 1)
            If myPos > 0 Then
                'Bold the string from B column
                Range("A" & i).Characters(myPos, Len(Range("B" & i).Value)).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: USING POSITION in the format 
MASTER_STR, SUBSTR1, POS1(START-END), SUBSTR2, POS2, e.t.c.

```
Sub t()

Dim heightA As Long
Dim heightB As Long
Dim height As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim length As Long
Dim tmp
Dim width As Long
heightA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
heightB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
If heightA < heightB Then
    height = heightA
Else
    height = heightB
End If

If height > 1 Then
    For i = 1 To height
        Range("A" & i).Font.Bold = False
        ''Replace the formula with the full string
        Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i).Value
        'Find the starting position of the string in B within the string produced by the formula
        width = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If width >= 3 Then
            For j = 3 To width Step 2
            If Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                    tmp = Split(Cells(i, j).Value, "-")
                    myPos = CLng(tmp(0))
                    length = CLng(tmp(1)) - myPos + 1
                    'myPos = InStr(1, Range("A" & i).Value, Range("B" & i).Value, 1)
                    If myPos > 0 Then
                        'Bold the string from B column
                        Range("A" & i).Characters(myPos, length).Font.Bold = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
ABCDEFG A   1-1 C   3-5
ABCDEFG A   1-1 C   3-3
```

Comment: if you need any explanation on the code, you can comment/chat me

Comment: I think so, but if Column C, E, ... and onwards already gives the position, then why do we need column B, D, ...

Comment: Yes,  Sorry I am not understanding your question completely, so now you want to KEEP your format, and want to A. Base on substring matching,  B. Base on Position given 

OR 

You are going to change the format to STRING,POSITION1,POSTITION2 ,...
Or  STRING, SUBSTR1, SUBSTR2, ...